# reassign synch object from within synchronized clause?

Tags: java, synchronization, mutex

I'm curious what the effects of the following would be:

```
Object mutex;
...  // mutex initialized in constructor etc.
public setMutex(Object mutex) {
    synchronized(this.mutex) {
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }
}
```

I've seen similar questions posed with advice against doing this kind of thing in other languages but, nothing specifically for Java.  I've also seen lots of questions about why one would possibly want to do this as it is seemingly self defeating code.

My rationale is that other critical sections of my code may be using the mutex when setMutex() is called and I don't want the mutex reassigned until those critical sections have exited.  So its not so much about guarding against race conditions on setting the mutex as it is maintaining the integrity of what the mutex is protecting.  I hope that makes sense :)

Personally I think it should work just fine, but I really don't know.

EDIT: removed the "synchronized" keyword from the method signature...musta brainfartet while I was typing.

Comment: A good IDE (Netbeans) would even report a warning "synchronizing on a non-final field", so it's better to mark the field and final to avoid accidental assignments to it.

Comment: got the warning (intellij), but its still occasionally necessary to reassign the synch object. but yeah its -usually- a mistake.

Comment: Use `synchronized` on the method, not on object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats really dangerous. First this synchronized block doesn't change it's behaviour at all.

Another thread that is using this synchronized block (or another based on this.mutex), will *probably* synchronize on another instance, but may not depending on whether or not the thread cached the this.mutex field.

See [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)

Comment: If I understand your point on thread caching, your are saying that if mutex was marked volatile will get rid of the caching.  Maybe I'm misreading the documentation but it seems to say variables accesed within the synchronized block are updated upon entrance to the block anyway.  I'll go back and reread that though.  Anyhow, back to the "will probably synchronize on another instance" comment, I see your point.  I'm going to think about this for a little bit and either come back with another comment or accept the answers given.  Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think this is even the biggest problem.  If the thread T1 is blocked on an object it got via mutex field, it will remained blocked on that mutex even if another thread changes what mutex field refers to.  At which point I fail to see any meaningful semantics.

Comment: agreed - thats what I thought you were alluding to with your comment on "will probably synchronize on another instance".  sounds like this was probably a dead end, but my head goes at its own slow speed so im still thinking it through.

Comment: ok I'm officially abandoning this idea.  thx for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this serves any meaningful purpose.  Everybody who is waiting on the old value of the "mutex" field to enter monitor will still be waiting on the original object and the new arrivals will wait on the new value.
Don't understand why the value of your synchronization primitive would ever need to change.

Comment: I have a threaded class X that needs to synchronize with another threaded class Y whose code I cannot modify and uses its self as its synchronization object.  During runtime an instance of X needs to synchronize against an ever changing instance of Y.  Since I can't make Y synchronize on X, I have to come up with a way of making X synchronize on an ever changing Y.  Its actually a bit more complex than that, but thats to basic idea.

Comment: In any case I'm starting to see the futility of my proposed approach.